# Toggle visibility of form fields if radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, toggle

I'm trying to hide a set of form fields initially. Then if a radio button is selected, show that group of fields. Then if that radio is deselected, hide them again.

The first two are working fine (hide fields initially, show them if radio is selected). But I can't get them to hide again when the radio is deselected. I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure out what it is.

http://jsfiddle.net/C5PMy/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

toggleFields(); //call this first so we start out with the correct visibility depending on the selected form values

    //Hide the fields initially
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105966-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105967-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105968-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105978").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105969-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105970").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105979").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105971-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105972").hide(); 


//Show the fields only if lodging is required
       $("#custom-105965_0").change(function () {
    toggleFields();
});


});
//this toggles the visibility of the other lodging fields depending on the current     selected value of the "lodging required" field
function toggleFields() {
if ($(("#custom-105965_0").checked)) {

    $("#bsd-field-custom-105966-group").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105967-group").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105968-group").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105978").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105969-group").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105970").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105979").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105971-group").show();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105972").show();
            }

            else  {
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105966-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105967-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105968-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105978").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105969-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105970").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105979").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105971-group").hide();
    $("#bsd-field-custom-105972").hide();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RL797/)</kbd>

Change

```
function toggleFields() {
    if ($("#custom-105965_0").is(':checked')) {
```

and

```
$(".custom-105965").change(function () {//assign change handler to both radio buttons
        toggleFields();
});
```

---

Better and Short version of your code

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RL797/1)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").hide();
    $(".custom-105965").change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'Yes') {
            $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").show();
        } else {
            $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

---

More shorter version

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/RL797/3)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").hide();//hide all
    $(".custom-105965").change(function () {//change event on radio button
        $("[id^=bsd-field-custom-1059]").toggle(this.value == 'Yes'); //if selected radio button has value yes than return true i.e show else false i.e hide
    });
});
```

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

[.toggle( showOrHide )](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't use the 'attribute starts with' part to shorten the code because there are actually more fields on the live page that start with that same string that I don't want to hide. But very helpful for future reference. Thank you!